# <await> multiple promises in Marko

Tags: javascript, asynchronous-javascript, marko

In Marko, how can one `<await>` multiple promises in parallel?

For example, I am looking for something like this:

```
<await(promise1, promise2)>
  <@then|result1, result2|>
    promise1 and promise2 are resolved in parallel
    ${result1} renders whenever it is ready.
    ${result2} renders whenever it is ready.
  </@then>
</await>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to accomplish this.

```
<await(Promise.all([promise1, promise2]))>
  <@then|[result1, result2]|>
    promise1 and promise2 are resolved in parallel
    ${result1} renders whenever it is ready.
    ${result2} renders whenever it is ready.
  </@then>
</await>
```

This would run the `@then` block once all of the promises have finished.

Answer (score 1):

I would add in addition to @Piercey4's response that if you have multiple  tags, they run in parallel, so if you don't need the results together, you can wrap them separately:

```html
promise1 and promise2 are resolved in parallel

<await(promise1)>
  <@then|result1|>
    ${result1} renders whenever it is ready.
  </@then>
</await>

<await(promise2)>
  <@then|result2|>
    ${result2} renders whenever it is ready.
  </@then>
</await>
```

With the default (in-order) flushing, `promise2` will be evaluated and rendered in parallel with `promise1`, but if `promise1` is not yet finished the content will be buffered to preserve HTML source order.
However, this would allow the content for `promise1` to arrive earlier if it finished first.